# Image is not uploaded through android app with PHP 8 in a new linux server

Tags: php, linux, http, nginx

In a shared host Linux server,
I have a PHP code which uploads an image on the server
On the other side I have an Android application which sends http post request to upload the image
**Everything is working fine**

Now I've purchased a Linux server which is not a shared host
In other word, I have complete control over the server

I've installed Nginx and php 8 (php version on the shared host was 5)
Now

> $_FILES

on the server side has nothing in it
In other words, the image is not uploaded at all

To test more I utilized the following codes to see if I ignore the Android application what will happen and everything worked fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

So I feel Android request is not truly processed here while it was ok in the shared host
Following you could see the main part of the Android application too:

```
 public static String ServiceCall_TextCommand(String mFileName, String mFileDestination, String mFileData) {

        Log.e("asa", "proprotttwwww 13 ");
        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        //String fileName = sourceFileUri;
        String fileName = mFileName;
        //String fileName = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/A5.png";


        //String fileName = "JSONFile.json";

        String upLoadServerUri = null;
        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = mFileDestination;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        //int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        int bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        //int maxBufferSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        //int maxBufferSize = 1024 ;
        /*File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + sourceFileUri);
            return "0";
        }
        else {*/

        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(json);
            //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);




            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;boundary=" + boundary);

            //conn.setRequestProperty("userfile", fileName);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(fileInputStream.available()));


            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
            //                + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

            //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename="
            //                + fileName + "" + lineEnd);


            //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
            //        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);






            //int length = fileInputStream.available();
            //Log.e(TAG, "lllllllllllllllllll: "+length);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            //bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            //int totalBytes = bytesAvailable;

            //bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bufferSize = mFileData.length();
            //buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            buffer = mFileData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            //buffer = mFileData.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));








            // read file and write it into form...
            //bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            //int cnt =0,cnt2;
            //while (bytesRead > 0) {
            //cnt++;
            //publishProgress(""+(int)((cnt*100)/1000));
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            //bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            //bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);



            //cnt++;
            //cnt2 = (cnt*100*maxBufferSize)/totalBytes;
            //Log.e(TAG, "llbytesRead:cnt2 = "+cnt2+"Total ="+totalBytes);
            ////publishProgress(""+cnt2);
            //publishProgress(""+50);


            //}

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("BBBuploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            Log.e("sasssssile", "xxxxm File Name : "
                    + mFileName);

            Log.e("sasssssile", "xxxxm File Data : "
                    + mFileData);




            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Completeeee ");
            }
            else
            {
                return  Constants.ServerResponse_Error_General;
            }

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            //Log.d(TAG, "AAe Start ................ " + total.toString().length());

            //long mCounter = 0;


            try
            {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
//                    mCounter++;
  //                  Log.e(TAG, "AAe mCounter = " +mCounter);
    //                Log.e(TAG, "AAe line = " +line);
                    //Log.e(TAG, "AAe in = " +in);

                    total.append(line).append('\n');
                    //Log.e(TAG, "AAe total = " +total);
      //              Log.e(TAG, "total size = " + total.toString().length());
                }

                /*for (line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
                    mCounter++;
                    //Log.e(TAG, "AAe mCounter = " +mCounter);
                    //Log.e(TAG, "AAe line = " +line);
                    //Log.e(TAG, "AAe in = " +in);

                    total.append(line).append('\n');
                    //Log.e(TAG, "AAe total = " +total);
                    //Log.e(TAG, "total size = " + total.toString().length());
                }*/


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log.e("asa", "proprotttwwww 177777 ");
            }

            //Log.e(TAG, "AAe mCounter2 = " +mCounter);


            //Log.d(TAG, "AAe End ................ " + total.toString().length());



            Log.d(TAG, "AAAServer Response total.toString().length is BB: " + total.toString().length());

            //Log.d(TAG, "AAAServer Response1111 is: " + total.toString() + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            largeLog(TAG,"AAAServer Response1111 is: " + total.toString() + ": " + serverResponseCode);




            //Log.d(TAG, "AAAServer Response is: " + total.toString() + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //close the streams //
            //fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            // Verify Command Response Checksum
            String mServerResponse = total.toString();
            mServerResponse = getStringBetween(mServerResponse,"@#@","#@#");
            Log.e("sds", "Server Response #######between########### Data:"+ mServerResponse);

            if (ValidateChecksum_WithoutCheckRange(mServerResponse) == false)
            {
                Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## Error: ValidateChecksum");
                return Constants.ServerResponse_Error_General;
            }
            Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## : ValidateChecksum: TRUE");

            String mCommand_Response_CommandName = SubString(mServerResponse,0,2);
            String mCommand_Send_CommandName     = SubString(mFileData,0,2);
            if (Validate_CommandResponse_CommandName(mCommand_Send_CommandName,mCommand_Response_CommandName) == false)
            {
                Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## Error: CommandName");
                return Constants.ServerResponse_Error_General;
            }
            Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## : CommandName: TRUE");

            String mCommand_Response_UserID = SubString(mServerResponse,0,2);
            String mCommand_Send_UserID     = SubString(mFileData,0,2);
            if (Validate_CommandResponse_UserID(mCommand_Send_UserID,mCommand_Response_UserID) == false)
            {
                Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## Error: UserID");
                return Constants.ServerResponse_Error_General;
            }
            Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## : UserID: TRUE");

            String mCommand_Response_MagicCode = SubString(mServerResponse,0,2);
            String mCommand_Send_MagicCode     = SubString(mFileData,0,2);
            if (Validate_CommandResponse_MagicCode(mCommand_Send_MagicCode,mCommand_Response_MagicCode) == false)
            {
                Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## Error: MagicCode");
                return Constants.ServerResponse_Error_General;
            }
            Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## : MagicCode: TRUE");

            return mServerResponse;

            /*if (ProcessCommandResponse(helper,mCommand_Response_CommandName,mServerResponse) == false)
            {
                Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## Error: ProcessCommandResponse =>"+mCommand_Response_CommandName);
                return Constants.ServerResponse_Error_ProcessCommandResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("sds", "Server Response ################## Success");
                return Constants.ServerResponse_Success;
            }*/




            /*if (total.toString().contains("Move successful") == true )
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Move To Server successful");
                return "Move To Server successful";
            }
            else if (total.toString().contains("JSONLastFile =") == true)
            {
                String FileNum = getBetweenStrings(total.toString(),"JSONLastFile =","dump end");
                Log.e(TAG, "Dump Ok , FileNum = "+FileNum);


                if (FileNum.length() >= 12) //Phone Number
                {
                    return total.toString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return FileNum;
                }



            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Move To Server Failed");
                return "Move To Server Failed";
            }*/

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            Log.e("asa", "proprotttwwww 18 ");
            //dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return Constants.ServerResponse_Error_General;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("asa", "proprotttwwww 19 ");
            //dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "111222Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return Constants.ServerResponse_Error_General;
        }


        //}
        //dialog.dismiss();
        //return serverResponseCode;
    } // End else block
```

Another strange point is when I check the

> /Var/log/nginx/error.log

I see the following code which indicated this is a get http request not a Post one:

```
2022/07/21 05:29:41 [error] 1881#1881: *875 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:
And
    request: "GET /upload.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host:
```

Comment: Unlikely that the Android part of this decided willy-nilly to switch from a POST to a GET request. More likely, that there is a redirect happening from the server side, which the app then follows up on by making a subsequent GET request ...

Comment: What URL are you actually sending this to now? Your HTML test form has action `upload2.php`, the commented-out URL in your Android code is `/DB/upload3.php`(and which one you are really passing for `mFileDestination`, we don't know), and the log entry you quoted is `/upload.php`

Comment: Ok, so you mean the original request is POST and then something in server side causes that the App sends a GET request which is another http request + the original http POST request

Comment: My test code is composed of 2 documents: the first one is html code and the upload2.php is what I added above after the html code.  About android code I use another php code on the server and I did not brought the upload.php code above since there is nothing in $_FILE at all so that the upload.php related to Android code would be important but if need be I can bring the upload.php code too

Comment: _"and about android code I use another php code on the server"_ - but if your HTML form and your Android app are targeting different scripts - then what does the fact that the former works, actually prove in regard to the latter?

Comment: I think there is no much difference there but Yes the targets are different so I check it with the same target too

Comment: I checked with the same target and again the problem persists, in fact when I print $_FILE just Array() is returned while with the test code it prints all the expected data

Comment: The GET request appears to be the problem, you lose the POST data at that point - so you'll have to figure out, where that redirect comes from, and disable it.

Comment: If `http://www.koalaapp.ir/...` is really the URL you are using - those all appear to automatically redirect to the HTTPS version. So specify the HTTPS version of the URL directly in your Android code then.

Comment: I use https too but the problem persists

Comment: When I add conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false ); then the server response is Moved Permanently: 301

Comment: You'll need to figure out what causes this redirect. We can hardly do that from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

The problem was just adding www to the url address from Android side
I changed

> https://www. example.com/upload2.php

to

> https:// example.com/upload2.php

and the problem was solved
The point is in the server administration panel, I had set that every

> www. example.com

request would be automatically redirected to

> example.com

Now I reversed it and the problem is solved with the following url from Android side:

> https://www. example.com/upload2.php